# How to access every ViewController from appDelegate?

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, viewcontroller, appdelegate

my problem is I am working with Alamofire and I added AlamofireActivityIndicator from :
[AlamofireNetworkActivityIndicator GitHub](https://github.com/Alamofire/AlamofireNetworkActivityIndicator)

my question is how to add a view to which viewController that user is there and doing networking request , that view shows indicator instead of showing indicator in status bar !

I have a problem and I changed framework codes to :

Original code from AlamofireNetworkActivityIndicator framework :

```
private var activityIndicatorState: ActivityIndicatorState = .notActive {
    didSet {
        switch activityIndicatorState {
        case .notActive:
            isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
            invalidateStartDelayTimer()
            invalidateCompletionDelayTimer()
        case .delayingStart:
            scheduleStartDelayTimer()
        case .active:
            invalidateCompletionDelayTimer()
            isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
        case .delayingCompletion:
            scheduleCompletionDelayTimer()
        }
    }
}
```

and I've been added two method that creates and remove a red view 50*50 center of screen , I customize it later that will show indicator

```
fileprivate func myIndicatorView (superView:UIView) {
    let view = UIView.init()
    view.tag = 2018
    view.backgroundColor = .red
    superView.addSubview(view)
    view.frame = CGRect(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.midX-25,
                        y: UIScreen.main.bounds.midY-25,
                        width: 50,
                        height: 50)
}

fileprivate func removeIndicatorView (superView:UIView) {
    superView.subviews.forEach{ (myView) in
        if myView.tag == 2018 {
            myView.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }
}
```

, but now my question is here :

```
private var activityIndicatorState: ActivityIndicatorState = .notActive {
    didSet {
        switch activityIndicatorState {
        case .notActive:
            self.myIndicatorView(superView: <#T##UIView#>)
            isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
            invalidateStartDelayTimer()
            invalidateCompletionDelayTimer()
        case .delayingStart:
            scheduleStartDelayTimer()
        case .active:
            self.removeIndicatorView(superView: <#T##UIView#>)
            invalidateCompletionDelayTimer()
            isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
        case .delayingCompletion:
            scheduleCompletionDelayTimer()
        }
    }
}
```

### Question :

how to define ViewControllers view instead of <#T##UIView#> ! ?? ? 
this framework usage is you type one line in appDelegate and it observer for every networking request :

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    NetworkActivityIndicatorManager.shared.isEnabled = true
    return true
}
```

Comment: what you basically want your question is not clear ?

Comment: @vivekDas in the [Question :] part i asked that ! how to add any ViewControllers view to custom classes from appDelegate

Comment: how to add any ViewControllers view to custom classes from appDelegate ? what do you mean by this ? What you want to achieve ?

Comment: @vivekDas i wanted to add view for every networking request based on networking request time !

Comment: Do you want to display activity indicator view for the network calls ?

Comment: @vivekDas yes but not like AlamofireActivityIndicator in status bar ! i want to show in center of screen

Comment: Okay, use this framework its very easy to do : https://github.com/SVProgressHUD/SVProgressHUD whenever you make a network call just show it and on completion just dismiss.

Comment: @vivekDas Great ! - it is in Objective-C but in documents it says that swift is possible , can you provide some codes in swift as answer ? ;)

Comment: are u using CocoaPods in your project ?

Comment: @vivekDas yes i use CocoaPods and have podfile

Comment: Okay, I have added my ans. please check it.

Comment: It's fairly easy to do yourself, just show the loading view on the statusBar window level, and handle it by a singleton class, dont even need to access any viewcontroller

Comment: 1. You don't need a third party dependency to handle your network requests. 2. Don't abuse application delegate to support your broken code design.

Comment: Wrong way of thinking. Post/listen notification instead

Comment: @CZ54 can you provide some code?

Comment: @mohamadrezakoohkan Done as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of trying to reach the specific controller, you should broadcast a message using the Notification Pattern.

Add following line to send "Add Loader Message"

`NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "AddLoader", object: nil)`

Add following to dismiss:

`NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "HideLoader", object: nil)`

And Now in every controller ( easier if you have a `Super` View controller ):

- In viewWillAppear:

`NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(yourShowSelector), name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "AddLoader"), object: nil)
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(yourHide
Selector), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "HideLoader"), object: nil)`

- In viewWillDisappear

  `NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)`

Comment: Great !! You rock \m/

Answer (score 1):

your question not clear . but i think you want to fetch your last controller from where  user is doing networking request.

Please use this code to fetch last viewcontroller from anywhere from app

```
extension UIApplication {

  class func topViewController(_ base: UIViewController? = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController) -> UIViewController? {
      if let nav = base as? UINavigationController {
         return topViewController(nav.visibleViewController)
      }
      if let tab = base as? UITabBarController {
         if let selected = tab.selectedViewController {
            return topViewController(selected)
         }
      }
      if let presented = base?.presentedViewController {
        return topViewController(presented)
      }
      return base
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So if you are using CocoaPods then you can use SVProgressHUD easily in your project to show activity indicator. Check the below link

https://github.com/SVProgressHUD/SVProgressHUD

First, add the following line to your Podfile:

**pod 'SVProgressHUD'**

Second, install SVProgressHUD into your project:

**pod install**

add the following line to your Podfile:

**use_frameworks!**

Thats it, now you can do import SVProgressHUD ans use its methods.

Check the image below for reference.

[image]

After completing the above process successfully just do the following:

1. do import SVProgressHUD
2. use like SVProgressHUD.show() before making any network call
3. use like SVProgressHUD.dismiss() on the completion callback.

Comment: how to use this framework ? where should i enable this ?

Comment: Edited the ans plz check now.